# TestNG-functionality not recognized by Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to use TestNG to test my Java-code. The TestNG-plugin is installed in IntelliJ, and the dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
</dependency>
```

has been added to Maven. However, when I write "@Test" in a class, IntelliJ gives the error-message: "can not resolve symbol 'Test'.

Importing org.testng.annotations.Test is not recognized either. It just seems like Intellij is ignoring the Maven-dependency.

Here is the project structure and the error:

[image]

Should I have done something more with TestNG, rather then just adding the Maven dependency?

Comment: `mvn clean install`

Comment: Try right-clicking signing-spring, or even dc16-signing and choose _maven -> reimport_.

Comment: Besides the above, in which pom did you add the Test-NG dependency? P.S. you should also add a [<scope>test</scope>](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) to its definition

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the problem was fixed. Just needed to clean install :) But I will remember the other tips as well

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `mvn clean`
2. Set the `scope` of `testng` to `test`, i.e.:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
       <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
       <version>6.12</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Run `mvn install`